# USB on board switching tools on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-activity, usb

I have an E3131 modem that does not switch the good way when connected to the PPP widget 2 on Android 4.2.2. I asked about this in the dedicated forum for this widget 
http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2312
what can I do and I was told that there is someting that is sending a low level command to the USb to switch my modem the wring way. Explicitly I was told

"The only reliable way I see is to disable (rename) the on-board switching tools so that they do not interfere with the mode-switching of PPP Widget 2."

What i am supposed to do? Which are these on-board switchng tools that I need to rename, that were referred ? All help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found the answer to my question.

Comment: You can post your answer, so that others may find it useful. `:)`